# How to read numbers from standard input, add and write the sum into standard output in R?

Tags: r

Hi I need my R script to read numbers from standard input, add the numbers and write the sum into standard input.

There can be two ways as below. One way is:

```
while (there is next line) {
  add the number to the list
}
sum = add(list of numbers)
print sum
```

Another way is:

```
while (there is next line) {
  sum = sum + next number
}
print sum
```

My code is reading the numbers from the file and have errors as I am new to R.

```
numbers <- scan("", what = integer())


for (i in 1:length(numbers)) {
  sum = sum + i
}


sum
```

Comment: The command you are looking for is scan() - type ?scan to get help. But before you do I think you need to stop and read an R Intro before ploughing on.

Comment: readline() or scan() is for input and print() is for output

Comment: scan and readline accepts input once, but I want to read several numbers, one at each line in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numbers <- scan()
sum(numbers)
```

Or:

```
sum(scan())
```

Is this what you mean?

```
mySum <- 0
for(i in 1:3){
  mySum <- mySum + sum(scan(n=1))
  print(mySum)
}
```

Comment: sum(scan()) for taking input from user and displaying the calculated sum

Comment: scan and readline accepts input once, but I want to read several numbers, one at each line in a loop.

Comment: @user3022609 use `n=1` option for scan, see my edited answer.

Comment: But I don't know how many lines I will be scanning. So instead of running for loop 3 times, I want it to run until no more lines are recieved through stdin.

Comment: @user3022609 Then just use `sum(scan())`